# Bluetooth button missing from Action Center on Windows 10 system with VMWare client installed

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, bluetooth, vmware, action-center

**Problem:** You have a Windows 10 system where the Bluetooth button is missing from the Action Center (the notifications panel), and all bluetooth features of Windows seem to be disabled. Furthermore, the problem may be intermittent; sometimes the bluetooth features are there, and sometimes not. In Windows Settings > Devices, any bluetooth devices may simply say "Bluetooth is turned off".

Comment: (1) In *Settings > Devices > Bluetooth & other devices*, is Bluetooth set to On? If not, try to set it. (2) In the Services applet, is "Bluetooth Support Service" running? If not, try to start it.

Answer (score 1):

Another setting for VMware to consider is Overall Preferences.

Edit, Preferences, USB and make sure it is set to ASK.

Then (as also suggested) make sure the Guest setting for USB is set to Share Bluetooth devices with Virtual Machine.

Do both and when you connect a Bluetooth device, VMware will ask if you wish to connect to (a) Host or (b) Guest.

[image]

Comment: Ahh interesting. I don't have those options. This company locks down a lot of stuff. I'm a database manager & dev and I can't even have local admin access to my dang pc. I'll suggest modifying these settings to the IT manager. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Cause:** If VMWare is installed, and a VM is running, it may be redirecting the USB bluetooth device from the system to the VM. This may be the case for other VM packages as well, such as Oracle VirtualBox (aka Vbox), or Microsoft Virtual PC.  This can also affect other USB devices, such as flash drives, printers, etc.

**Solution:** Check the VMWare "Connect USB Device" menu for a bluetooth device and un-check it, as shown below. This holds true for other listed USB devices as well. Any device on this menu that's checked will be redirected to the VM and made unavailable to the system which the VM is running on:

[image]